# Google Maps API v3: Problem drag and drop jquery with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, drag-and-drop

The idea is to drag elements from outside Google map DIV and drop them into Google maps, then a marker must be placed in the lat/long where the element was dropped.

Basically i created two global variables for the javascript

```
var latFromMap;var longFromMap;
```

...

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
        latFromMap = event.latLng.lat();
        longFromMap = event.latLng.lng();
        document.getElementById("positionLatLng").innerHTML = event.latLng.lat() + "  +++++++  " + event.latLng.lng();
   });
```

As you can see the lat/long is always captured into those variables, so i can create a marker.

Then i have an element with JQUERYUI drag/drop when it's dropped then a marker is added. When i'm using FF/Chrome it works fine, but when i'm using IE the position is not registered while i'm on the "dragging" time.

Anyone can help me out with this ?

Regards

George

PS. Here you may see what i'm trying to accomplish:

http://www.cheiscorp.com/newUI/LocatorTesterv05.html

Answer (score 1):

You prob. need to calculate the lat/lng coordinate of the mouse cursor yourself to get it running in all browsers.

This means you have to keep polling the mouse position on the map div and get the matching coordinate with the helper functions of gmaps (see http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection)